# Why the icon disapear if I use TouchableOpacity on ReactNative and NativeBase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm using React Native and NativeBase.

I just try to show an icon next to an entry and add TouchableOpacity to after trigger a function, but the icon disapear

This is my code:

```
              <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label>Password</Label>
                  <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    secureTextEntry={ this.state.securePass }
                    onChangeText = { value => this.updateInput('password', value)}
                    value = { this.state.form.password.value }  
                    type = { this.state.form.password.type }             
                  />
                   <TouchableOpacity>
                      <Icon name='eye'  type="FontAwesome" style={ styles.iconFont } />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </Item>
```

If I put this code outside the Item of nativeBase works but no inside:

```
               <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Icon name='eye'  type="FontAwesome" style={ styles.iconFont } />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

I hope you can helpme!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
<TouchableOpacity>
                      <Icon name='eye'  type="FontAwesome" style={ styles.iconFont } />
                  </TouchableOpacity>    
<Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label>Password</Label>
                  <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    secureTextEntry={ this.state.securePass }
                    onChangeText = { value => this.updateInput('password', value)}
                    value = { this.state.form.password.value }  
                    type = { this.state.form.password.type }             
                  />

              </Item>
</View>
```